Why does Google data studio treat my existing fields as new?
When I try to refresh the fields from my data source (Google sheet), Google data studio lists my existing fields as new fields. If I apply these changes it breaks my charts so that I have to redo them. Does anybody know why this is happening? Seems like there might have been a similar bug years ago that was resolved at the time.
